# Issue with making duplicate Xib files

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I want to duplicate my Xib file several times. What's the best way to do this? Do I also need to duplicate .h and .m from the original?

Comment: Why do you need to duplicate your nib? You can use the same nib file over several view controllers using the initWithNibName selector.

Comment: I need 3 different xibs with very little change to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new UIViewController Subclass and copy and paste all of the contents of your XIB files. Or just create multiple views in one XIB file?

Comment: Drag a new view into the XIB file. Then, in the .h file, define the views (under the @interface line between the brackets: UIView *view1;, etc.). Then, link these in the XIB file to the views. And then, in the .m file, when you want one view to show (this is where you would change XIB files, but you're changing views instead), type this: [self.view bringSubviewToFront:view1]; Does this make sense? I'll try to explain it better, but for my first app I tried using multiple XIB files because it was easier, even though a lot more time consuming.

Comment: I just want to duplicate a certain view two more times. I know how to navigate between views. My main concerns is when duplicating original xib will I also have to duplicate .m and .h?

Comment: I really don't know about using multiple XIBs with .h and .m files. I just have all three files. I read above that it's very little change. Let's say you are changing text. Why not just change the text instead of creating whole new views and files? You'll save a lot of time.

Comment: I need to add two more views. The little changes will be UIActionLabels to navigate between the three views. The three views are 3 views that the user enters information.

Comment: UIActionLabels don't exist. Did you mean UILabels or UIActionSheets? Anyway, if the user successfully completes one form, such as Form 1, which contains two text boxes and is ready to move to form 2, do this: [textField1 setHidden:YES]; [textField2 setHidden:YES];, [texField3 setHidden:NO];, [textField4 setHidden:NO];, and hide textfield3 and textfield4 in viewDidLoad. See where I'm going with this?